# What is my string::find() doing here

Tags: c++, string

I have following code (simplified):

```
std::string file = "TestName.raw.craw";
int index1 = file.find_last_of(".craw");
int index2 = file.find_last_of(".raw");
```

Why is index1 == index2 after this? (both are 16)

Is the . skipped for some reason, or something? I checked at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx and the point was not in the list of characters that need to be escaped, so what is happening here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`find_last_of()` finds the last occurrence of *any* character that appears in its argument. Here, it's the final `w` in both cases.

You should use `rfind()` to find the last occurrence of a substring in any string.

Answer (score 2):

`find_last_of` searches the string for the last character that matches any of the characters specified in its arguments(the second parameter in the function)

In your case, it is printing the index of character `w` i.e.16

Please refer [THIS](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_last_of) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

`std::string::find_last_of` does not find the last instance of a substring, but finds the last character that matches one of the characters in the input string.  So in this case, both of them are finding the `w`, and returning the index to that.

What you want is `std::string::rfind`

Answer (score 0):

From the string "TestName.raw.craw", both find_last_of finds the last occurence at the same place